# ArgumentNullException in WindsorControllerActivator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a project with multiple layers(assemblies). I used **Castle Windsor** to solve Dependency Injection. Also create my controllers with castle. so I installed and used castle in Web API and WebUI Layers too. Beside I have a bootstrapper layer which registers all services and repositories.

**First my  web API:**

In WebApiConfig.cs file, I registered UI Dependencies with flowing code:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(corsAttr);

        // Web API configuration and services
        var container = Bootstrapper.WireUp();// to register services and repositories
        RegisterControllers(container);
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new WindsorControllerActivator(container));

    }

    private static void RegisterControllers(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        //container.Register(Component.For<VisitorController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        //container.Register(Component.For<ValueController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        //container.Register(Component.For<ValidateController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        //container.Register(Component.For<CaptchaImageController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<VisitorController>()
            .BasedOn<ApiController>().LifestyleTransient());
    }
```

And activator factory is like this:

```
 public class WindsorControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;
    public WindsorControllerActivator(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        return (IHttpController)_container.Resolve(controllerType);//System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. error
    }
}
```

Also in WebUI project I used **Castle Windsor** to create my controllers. But when I run the project I get "**System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.**" error when is resolving Controller.I mean in this line:

```
(IHttpController)_container.Resolve(controllerType);
```

I also tried "LifeStylePerWebRequest" for my controllers and nothing were changed.

Whats more, nothing is wrong with WireUp Method,(Registering service and repositories works fine). This problem is just for controllers(in WebUI and WebApi projects). Same problem happens for WebUI project.

Comment: show the stack trace for the exception.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint inside the Create method, you can examine the dependencies that have been registered. Is the controllerType one of them? Also as a side note, don't forget to release the controller if you are using Transient lifestyle. You can have a look at this post http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectioninASP.NETWebAPIwithCastleWindsor/

Comment: i used LifestylePerWebRequest in WebUI and i get same error.

Comment: For disposing you can have a look at the blog post I have included in my previous comment. You basically use HttpRequestMessage. But that won't solve your problem of null exception. Have you tried to debug and put the breakpoint on the line that is erroring? Do you see the type of controller that is being reuested as controllerType registered correctly. Is there any chance that _container is NULL and your Bootstrapper.WireUp() is retrurning NULL?

Comment: I tested that Bootstrapper.WireUp() in never returning null. I used the release method in the blog you posted (thanks) . but nothing where changed. What is wired for me is that in WebUI, sometimes it gets that error and some times it wont.

Comment: When it does error, could you check if either _container or controllerType is NULL?

Comment: in local _container or controllerType is not NULL. but in server it is. here is my error. 500 Internal Server Error--->Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: service.--->Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Comment: dear @RVid here is my error:[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: service] Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelI‌​nternal.LoadHandlerB‌​yType(String name, Type service, IDictionary arguments) +552

Answer (score 1):

I normally use implementation of `IDependencyResolver` instead of `IHttpControllerActivator`. You can this approach instead. Add the floowing class:

```
public class WindsorDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public WindsorDependencyResolver(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(container));
        }

        _container = container;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new WindsorDependencyScope(this, _container.Release);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public object GetService(Type t)
    {
        var ret = _container.Kernel.HasComponent(t) ? _container.Resolve(t) : null;
        return ret;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type t)
    {
        var ret = _container.ResolveAll(t).Cast<object>().ToArray();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

This class is required by the dependency resolver:

```
public class WindsorDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
    {
        readonly List<object> _instances;
        readonly Action<object> _release;
        readonly IDependencyScope _scope;

        public WindsorDependencyScope(IDependencyScope scope, Action<object> release)
        {
            if (scope == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(scope));
            }

            if (release == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(release));
            }

            _scope = scope;
            _release = release;
            _instances = new List<object>();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            foreach (object instance in _instances)
            {
                _release(instance);
            }

            _instances.Clear();
        }

        public object GetService(Type t)
        {
            var service = _scope.GetService(t);
            AddToScope(service);

            return service;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type t)
        {
            var services = _scope.GetServices(t);
            AddToScope(services);

            return services;
        }

        void AddToScope(params object[] services)
        {
            if (services.Any())
            {
                _instances.AddRange(services);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how you register the the dependency resolver in you `Register` method:

```
config.DependencyResolver = new WindsorDependencyResolver(container);
```

I would recommend to register your controllers with lifestyle transient as the dependency resolver takes care of disposing them.

Comment: still same error occurs. I don't know what is the problem with server.

Comment: I used DI for WebApi layer and For WebUI Layer. but i tested with different assembly to create container. every container registered services and repositories separately. shouldn't i use same container for all layers?

Comment: You should only have a single container for an application instance. By Web UI, do you mean ASP.net MVC? I am not sure how is your solution structured but are your API controllers in the same application instance as MVC controllers? (that is if you are using MVC)

Comment: When using MVC and Web API in a single application instance you normally create a single container, register Web API routes first, register dependency resolver for Web API, then you register MVC routes and then register MVC controller factory. When you register Web API routes, normally you prefix the path with /api/ so the routes are correctly resolved between MVC and Web API.

Comment: I think i get what is my problem. I used one Domain and i wanted to have web api and ui in same domain. but I just published ui Layer and not publishing api layer. I cant add service reference to api layer. how to publish both on same domain?

Comment: You can have you MVC app that includes ApiControllers. If that is what you want than do all registration in Global.asax (Unless you are using owin Startup). Basicaly your MVC and Web API controllers will coexist. Scenario 2 on this blog post: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/01/on-the-coexistence-of-asp-net-mvc-and-webapi.aspx

Comment: Look at my comment couple of comments above: When using MVC and Web API in a single application instance... This is basically describing the scenario

Comment: but as i told they are in different project but same solution. what's more, if i remove api controller to mvc layer, How can I handle controller factory and IHttpControllerActivator?

Comment: For MVC controllers you have to use Controller factory. http://www.artisancode.co.uk/2014/04/integrating-windsor-castle-mvc/